# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint '' Cannot insert duplicate key in object ''. The duplicate key value is (,)

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Hello I have a code consisting of two parts of the problem in the tags.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id){
            if (id == null)
            {return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);}
            Post post = db.Posts.Find(id);

            StringBuilder tagList = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (Tag tag in post.Tags)
                {
                    tagList.AppendFormat("{0} ", tag.Name);
                }
                ViewBag.Tags = tagList.ToString();

            if (post == null){return HttpNotFound();}
            return View(post);}
```

Part 1 adds tags in line in same field.
Part 2 of the opposite line in tags.

```
 public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Title,DateTime,Body,Avtor")] Post post, string tags)
            {if (ModelState.IsValid){
                    db.Entry(post).State = EntityState.Modified;

                    post.Tags.Clear();
                    tags = tags ?? string.Empty;
                    string[] tagNames = tags.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    foreach (string tagName in tagNames)
                    {
                        post.Tags.Add(GetTag(tagName));
                    }

                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");}
                return View(post);}
```

problem in row "post.Tags.Clear();" it does not remove the connection, and I get an error:

```
"Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_PostsTags'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.PostsTags'. The duplicate key value is (1, 3).
The statement has been terminated."
```

in row "db.SaveChanges();", at least I think so, although I have little experience to speak with apparent confidence. I looked the other cases but it would help me not found. Please tell me where I go wrong?

Comment: is this an identity column?

Comment: It must be an identity or PK column as per the error.  The error is clearly telling you that you are trying to insert a record with a duplicate key.  If you intend to insert this way, remove the ID column from the insert and it will auto-generate the new identity value.

Comment: I have to the table and 2 keys postid tegid, it is necessary for a bunch of tables, many to many.

Comment: Make sure `post.Tags` is loaded before modifying it.

Comment: I've got a function to add a tag by post ID, but now I would like to delete all the current tags for that ID before adding my new tags?

Comment: I changed the PRIMARY KEY, and then get errors everywhere, no matter what page did not open, for example in return View (model.ToPagedList (pageNumber, pageSize)): Models.MyBlog.msl (90,6): error 3025: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 90: Must specify mapping for all key properties (PostsTags.Id) of table PostsTags.

Comment: @user3240336 Did you check what I said?

Comment: Gert Arnold yes I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand the problem "db.Entry (post). State = EntityState.Modified;" which retains only what is in the view, though not certain, because swapping nothing has changed. Had to create a post for each cell of your object and change view, all earned.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id, string avtor, string title, string body, string BodyPost, DateTime dateTime, string tags)
        {
                Posts post = db.Posts.Find(id);
                post.Title = title;
                post.Body = body;
                post.DateTime = dateTime;
                post.Tags.Clear();
                post.Avtor = avtor;

                tags = tags ?? string.Empty;
                string[] tagNames = tags.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                foreach (string tagName in tagNames)
                {
                    post.Tags.Add(GetTag(tagName));
                }
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
         }
<h5>Title:</h5><input type="text" name="title" value="@Model.Title" /><br />
<h5>Tags:</h5><input type="text" name="tags" value="@ViewBag.Tags" /><br />
<h5>DateTime:</h5><input type="text" name="dateTime" value="@Model.DateTime" /><br />
<h5>Body:</h5><textarea name="body" rows="10" cols="80"> @Model.Body</textarea><br />
<h5>Avtor:</h5><input type="text" name="avtor" value="@Model.Avtor" /><br />
```